# Cygwin audible ping?

Tags: cygwin, ping

ping -a works just like ping but no audible like on linux. I know there is bping tool for windows but I wanted to see if it was possible to have an audible ping using cygwin on win.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `man ping` ? There no `-a` option in cygwin's `/bin/ping` that's why it isn't beeping